# Proving there are not real roots for a parametric equation where inequality is given for the parameters

Tags: abstract-algebra, inequality

Let $a>0$ and $12a + 5b + 2c > 0$. Prove that it is not possible the equation $ax^2 +bx +c =0$ to have two real number roots in the interval $(2;3)$.

This is a high-school problem from a class focused on competitive maths and unfortunately I don't know how to solve it. I will appreciate a solution very much. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that you have the given real roots in the interval $(2,3)$. Then $$2<x_{1,2}<3$$
We can write this as $$(x_{1,2}-2)(x_{1,2}-3)<0$$
or $$x_{1,2}^2-5x_{1,2}+6<0$$
Since this is true for both roots, let's add the inequations together to get $$x_1^2+x_2^2-5(x_1+x_2)+12<0$$
Now we know that $x_{1,2}$ are roots of $ax^2+bx+c=0$, so we can write $$x_{1,2}^2=-\frac ba x_{1,2}-\frac ca$$
Plugging into the above inequation we get $$-\frac ba(x_1+x_2)-2\frac ca-5(x_1+x_2)+12<0$$
The sum of the roots is $-b/a$, so we get $$\frac {b^2}{a^2}-2\frac ca+5\frac ba+12<0$$
Multiply with $a$ and we get $$b^2/a-2c+5b+12a<0$$Let's add and subtract $2c$ on the left side, to get $$b^2/a-4c+(12a+5b+2c)<0$$
Since the quantity in parenthesis is greater than $0$, we can therefore write $$b^2/a-4c<0$$After multiplying with $a$ we get $$b^2-4ac<0$$ Going back to the quadratic equation, that means that the roots are not real.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_1,x_2$ be the roots of $0=ax^2+bx+c$. By the Viete identities, $b=-a(x_1+x_2)$ and $c=ax_1x_2$. Insert into the second inequality and divide by $a>0$ to find
$$
12-5(x_1+x_2)+2x_1x_2>0\tag{*}
$$
However
\begin{align}
&2\cdot(12-5(x_1+x_2)+2x_1x_2)
\\&=24-2⋅5(x_1+x_2)+(x_1+x_2)^2-(x_1-x_2)^2
\\
&=(5-x_1-x_2)^2-1-(x_1-x_2)^2.
\end{align}
Now by the assumption $x_1,x_2\in(2,3)$ one finds $|5-x_1-x_2|< 1$, so that the left side of (*) is always negative, invalidating this assumption.

---

One could also write the left side of (*)  as
$$
12-5(x_1+x_2)+2x_1x_2=(x_1-\tfrac52)^2+(x_2-\tfrac52)^2-\tfrac12-(x_1-x_2)^2
$$
which is also easily seen to be negative if $|x_k-\frac52|<\frac12$ for both $k=1$ and $k=2$.

---

Or also
$$
12-5(x_1+x_2)+2x_1x_2=(x_1-2)(x_2-3)+(x_1-3)(x_2-2).
$$